# Laravel mismatching IDs

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

My website currently has a weird bug that only shows itself on the live version, but not on my local setup.

Essentially, in this scenario, a user is trying to ask an artist (another type of user) for a quote, hence the `requestQuote` function.

```
public function requestQuote(Request $request, AppMailer $mailer) { 

    $reciUsername = $request->input('recipient');
    $recipientID = User::where('username', $reciUsername)->value('id');
    $recipient = User::where('username', $reciUsername)->first();
    $active_commissions_count = Commission::where('artist_id', $recipientID)
            ->where('complete', 0)
            ->where('stripe_charge_id', '!=', "")
            ->where('stripe_charge_id', '!=', null)         
            ->count();

    $this->validate($request, [
        'message' => 'required|max:5000|min:10',
    ]);


    $message = Auth::user()->messages()->create([
        'body' => $request->input('message'),
        'subject' => 'Status: Commission requested!',
        'recipient_id' => $recipientID,
        'sender_read' => 1,
        'is_quote' => 1,
        'quote_expires' => Carbon\Carbon::now()->addWeeks(1),
    ]);

    $from = Auth::user()->username;
    $mailer->sendQuoteRequestEmailTo($recipient, $from);

     Auth::user()->update([
        'timeout' =>  Carbon\Carbon::now(),
     ]);        

    dd("Message ID: " . $message->id . " - Message User ID: " . $message->user_id);

    return redirect()->back()->with('info', 'Quote sent.');
}
```

This creates a message which the artist can then read. In this scenario, the `recipient_id` user is the artist, and the `user_id` user is the one who made the original quote. This is not supposed to change at any point during this transaction.

You'll notice there's a diedump at the end there.

In this scenario, the dd returns

> "QUOTE REQUEST - Message ID: 30 - Message User ID: 2 - Recipient ID: 21"

Great. Everything works well so far, and the correct message is sent through, with the correct user being shown as having sent the quote.

The problem happens when the artist replies to the quote.

```
public function quoteReply(Request $request, $messageId, AppMailer $mailer) {

    $this->validate($request, [
        "reply-{$messageId}" => 'max:5000',
        "price" => 'required|min:10|max:9999|numeric',
        "date" => 'required|date',
            ], [
        'max' => 'The text body has a maximum of 5000 characters.',
        'price.max' => 'Commissions have a maximum of 9999 US dollars.',
        'price.min' => 'Commissions have a minimum of 10 US dollars.',
    ]);

    $message = Message::notReply()->find($messageId);

    if (!$message) {
        return redirect()->route('home')->with('info', 'Something went wrong.');
    }

    $date = $request->input('date');
    $date2 = DateTime::createFromFormat('m/d/Y', $date);
    $date3 = $date2->format("Y-m-d");

    $reply = message::create([
                'body' => $request->input("reply-{$messageId}"),
                'sender_read' => 3,
                'reci_read' => 3,
            ])->user()->associate(Auth::user());

    Message::where('id', $messageId)->update([
        'updated_at' => Carbon\Carbon::now(),
        'subject' => 'Status: Price quote delivered.',
        'quoted' => 1,
        'price' => $request->input('price'),
        'estimated_date' => $date3,
        'quote_expires' => Carbon\Carbon::now()->addWeeks(1),
    ]);

    $userID = $message->value('user_id');
    $recipientID = $message->value('recipient_id');
    $user = User::where('id', $userID)->first();


    if (Auth::user()->id == $userID) {
        Message::where('id', $messageId)->update(['reci_read' => 0]);
    }

    if (Auth::user()->id == $recipientID) {
        Message::where('id', $messageId)->update(['sender_read' => 0]);
    }

    $message->replies()->save($reply);

    $from = Auth::user()->username;
    $mailer->sendQuoteReplyEmailTo($user, $from);       


    dd("QUOTE REPLY - Message ID: " . $message->id . " - Message User ID: " . $message->user_id . " - Message Recipient ID: " . $message->recipient_id . " - User ID: " . $user->id );

    return redirect()->back()->with('info', 'Price quote delivered.');
}
```

This will return:

> "QUOTE REPLY - Message ID: 30 - Message User ID: 2 - Message Recipient
>   ID: 21 - User ID: 3"

I first noticed this problem when the wrong user was receiving email. In fact it's ALWAYS the same user getting the email. User 3. If I use a different user for the artist, and a different user for the person requesting the quote, `$user` always becomes user 3.

Despite this, the correct users are still getting correct messages. At the moment this is only affecting who's getting the correct email in the `quoteReply` function.

What could be causing this?

Comment: try changing `User::where('username', $reciUsername)->first()` to `User::where('username', $reciUsername)->get()` to start with. First will always return some sort of user object not matter if its exists or not. Also what version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: I'm currently using 5.4.

Comment: why wont you use laravel notification to send notification weather its email, sms or whatever. Also update `$user = User::where('id', $userID)->first();
` to `$user = User::where('id', $userID)->get();`

Comment: It's an old app. I don't use many of the current defaults.

Comment: 5.4 is not an old version of laravel. Notification came out with laravel 5.3 anyway. Update what I have suggested and let me know what happens

Comment: No I mean I've been using this app since 5.0.

Comment: Found the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Switching

```
$userID = $message->value('user_id');
```

to

```
$userID = $message->user_id;
```

Fixed my problem.

Comment: `$userID = $message->user_id` should do